# Implicit array length with C# PInvoke

Tags: c#, pinvoke

Given the following C API:

```
void foo(const char ** stringArray, size_t arrayCount);
```

I want to create a PInvoke adapter for it in C#. I can make a one-to-one mapping in C# as:

```
[DllImport("x.dll", ...)]  // char set, etc. omitted
public static extern void foo(string[] stringArray, int arrayCount);
```

I'd like an implicit second parameter.

```
// Psuedo-code
[DllImport("x.dll", ...)]
public static extern void foo(string[] stringArray, 
                              [MarshalAs(stringArray.Length)] int arrayCount);
```

Obviously the [MarshalAs()] part is made-up.

The goal is for the C# calling code to look like this:

```
string[] list = { "x", "y" };
foo(list);
```

I can make a simple wrapper around the PInvoke, but I was wondering if that is the best way, or if my PInvoke declaration can directly solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a wrapper function:

```
private static extern void foo(string[] stringArray, int arrayCount);

public static void foo(string[] stringArray) {
    foo(stringArray, stringArray.Length);
}
```

This is a far easier and more flexible solution.

Comment: Don't forget `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStr)]`